# Excel VBA Program to Automate Task: Find & Highlight Duplicates Based on Certain Conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have to complete a somewhat tedious task for an excel of about 10,000 entries. I have no experience with VBA, so I would appreciate your help.

Given the following data format, the program would:

[image]

1) Highlight  in green the oldest duplicate in a set of duplicates (duplicate denoted by Column A, age denoted by Column B)

2) Highlight the rest of the duplicates in a set in yellow

3) Copy the code in Column C of the oldest duplicate entry in a set (now highlighted in green) to column D for all the duplicated entries in that set (A1, A3, A4)

So the output would look like this:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you sort the sheet?  ie... sort by A, B then run a simple bit of code?

Comment: True about the sorting, but how do I highlight the oldest in green and the rest in yellow though?

Comment: Is this an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem X-Y problem? Who is going to now go through and analyse 10,000 entries highlighted yellow or green? Another solution may be to import into MS Access or SQL Express and run a query to make sense of it. And if you like you can export it out again to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a partial answer to point you in the right direction... hopefully it gets you close but I have not tested it so make sure you have a backup...

It assumes you can sort by col a and col b.  I found the color number from here: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicates()

SaveCompany = ""
SaveColC = ""

For Counter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set cola = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 1)
    Set ColB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 2)
    Set ColC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 3)
    Set ColD = ActiveSheet.Cells(Counter, 4)

    ' Highlight the first company record green
    If cola.Value <> SaveCompany Or SaveCompany = "" Then
        Range(cola, ColD).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        SaveColC = colc.value
    End If

    ' Highlight matching company record yellow and set value to oldest c
    If cola.Value = SaveCompany Then
        Range(cola, ColD).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        colc.value = SaveColC
    End If

    ' Save the company
    SaveCompany = cola.Value

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

In D1 write this array formula: (dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter to enter it)

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6;MATCH(MAX(IF(A1=$A$1:$A$6;$B$1:$B$6;""));IF(A1=$A$1:$A$6;$B$1:$B$6;"");0))
```

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

Copy the formula down

Now select A1:D6, goto conditional formatting, new rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Enter the formula :

```
=$C1=$D1
```

Apply Green background

Add another rule with the formula:

```
=AND($C1<>$D1;$D1<>"")
```

Apply the yellow background